# Firestore collectionGroup query doc.data() not found

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I try to retrieve the last 10 conditions based on diveDate field from subcollections that are in the path `/caves/{caveId}/conditions/{conditionId}`

I created the index in the Firestore console but I am getting a `doc.data() is not a function`

```
const db = admin.firestore();

const top10_conditions = db.collectionGroup('conditions').orderBy('diveDate', 'desc').limit(10).get().then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data())
})
```

There are definitely documents there

[image]

And the index is set

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you show here, `doc` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type document.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a method called `data()`.  It's not a DocumentSnapshot, which does have that method.  This explains the error.

Since the query can return multiple documents, you will need to write code to iterate those documents and look at the data for each matching document.  This is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

```
db.collectionGroup('conditions').orderBy('diveDate', 'desc').limit(10).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get()` function [returns a `QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which is an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`s that each have a `.data()` method.
Therefore you may only access these data using a loop over each document:

```js
const top10_conditions = db
  .collectionGroup('conditions')
  .orderBy('diveDate', 'desc')
  .limit(10)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
  })
```